# Cancel query or force onGeoQueryReady?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have in my database a part like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHvna.jpg): in that the app saves all the user locations and in various fragments of the app recover all the keys of the users that are near.

The problem is if i only wanna recover "X" keys (30 for example) and there are more than that number into the range of the query. When i recover, i save into a list that "X" keys, but the query retrieve all the keys in range anyway, and it costs too much time.

How can i can cancel the query when i want? Or force the onGeyQueryReady event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to cancel a query once it has started. Nor is there a way to limit a Geoquery to a certain number of results.

What you *can* do is to count the number of keys you've already received in `onKeyEntered`, and then stop processing further keys once you've gotten 30.

Comment: Yes, already i'm doing that, but it's relative slow... Because today are near me 200 users, and i wanna only the first 30, but if tomorrow are 2000 users, it's a lot of time wasted... Thanks either! Frank...